# tidy - How to remove duplicate ID's from HTML

Tags: php, html, parsing, tidy

I have a HTML that need to be parsed by `DOMDocument::loadHtml($html)`, but it gives me an error:

`DOMDocument::loadHTML(): ID 'my id' already defined in Entity`

I don't have control about the `$html`, but I can use tidy lib (or something else, ideas?) on it and make a parseable HTML.
But I'm not finding a option in tidy's config to remove duplicate ID's in tidy config. My code is like that:

```
$tidy = new tidy();
$tidy->parseString($this->getPageContents());
$html = new DOMDocument();
$html->loadHTML($tidy); // error here
```

Thx

Comment: A PHP lib http://php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$html->loadXML($tidy);
```

and than rewriting the id's using xml dom before parsing as html dom